# Email notification loss after system update

Tags: email, notifications

My Email notification used to work perfectly (with a beep). But after I updated the system, the Email notification disappeared (without any beep), even though the Email notification is still turned on. I didn't make any changes to that. How to resolve that.

ps: ios and system version 13

Comment: Is Silent Mode on?

Comment: Silent Mode isn't on

Comment: @Thinkr thx a lot resolved

Comment: What OS and version are you using? If you could edit that in the post it will help others find the answers they seek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check for the account-specific notifications (sound)

Check under **Settings** -> **Mail** -> **Notifications** -> **Customize notifications** -> [click on your *email account service* (ex. Gmail)] -> [make sure "Alerts" is *enabled*] -> **Sound** -> [select one sound you want, just be sure it's *not* set to "none"].